# Animate Collision On and Off

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

I have an object that a cloth is colliding with, and I want the collision to be disabled in the middle of the animation. However, I cannot just turn off object Collisions on the cloth, because there is another collision object that I want the cloth to continue interacting with. I cannot find an 'on/off' switch in the Collision properties. In another forum, scaling the collision object worked, but doesn't in my case because it pushes/pulls the cloth. Is there a way to animate collisions to turn off or another solution around this?
(I am using Blender 2.81a)

Comment: To essentially stop colliding with one particular object, or to have one cloth stop moving, and another one continue to react?

Comment: I want the cloth to react as normal to all objects. The only thing changing is that 1 object 'vanishes'

Comment: You could render animation to the point where the object disappears, delete the object, and render another animation starting from the point where the first animation left off. Combine the two scenes in an editor.

Comment: Technically, this question should be called "Animating the permeability of a cloth collision object".

Answer (score 0):

### The answer is: No

You can not directly animate the modifier so that it will be cloth-permeable, **but** you can easily find ways around it.

I fixed this problem by running a simple small animation myself, a cloth plane falling on a cube with collision settings, and a large plane (with collision settings to act as the floor).

I animated the cube with a *LocScale* keyframe at frame 1, 50, and 75.

At frame one I added a single keyframe to the cube without doing anything.

At frame 50, I did nothing to the cube, and set another keyframe.

At frame 75, I scaled the cube down to .0001 size, and moved it beneath the plane.

The final result is that the cube shrinks below the cloth, and gives the effect of the object disappearing.

I believe this is the best way to animate these kinds of simulations, so I hope this helps you.

Here is the .blend. (Note: you may need to re-bake the cloth):
[image]

[Here is a video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17xlU77fi9pS1ZxtG0xvSOjf53j0s26oA), too, if you don't want to have to download the .blend.